# Replacing smiles with images in Swing text area

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a chat system..i am making use of JText area to display chat, and JTextField to enter text.
My question is how to recognize smiley's like ":)" and replace it by corresponding image
on text area? i found no method which will append image on text area..Please help.

Comment: The title of your question is far too less specific, to reflect your intention.

Answer (score 5):

http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use a read-only [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) to display HTML instead of a `JTextArea` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea was made to display only multiple rows of **text**, but correct me if I'm wrong. To display Images you could use the [JEditorPane](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html) control that will allow you to use html, with simple `<img /`> tags which will point to a image.

Regarding how to recognize smileys you could create a file / list of common patterns that you would like to support and then simple check if the text contains the pattern with the .contains , or even Regular Expressions.

Update

And with the JEditorPane you will also be to do addition things like say scan for emails or links and automatically convert them so the user can click them, always a nice feature to have.